# .NET: Localize a time

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, localization, time

I need to create a `<select>` in my view an `<option>` for each hour (all 24 of them), localized to the current thread's time format.

How can I do this?

The output for en-US should look like:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">12:00 AM</option>
    <option value="1">1:00 AM</option>
    ...
    <option value="12">12:00 PM</option>
</select>
```

So far I've got:

```
<% For hour As Integer = 0 To 23 %>
    <option value="<%= hour.ToString() %>"></option>
<% Next %>
```

Comment: Not sure how you are using this, but if its to get the timezone of the client you can always do this by posting back the clients time and comparing. Again, this may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% For hour As Integer = 0 To 23 %>
    <option value="<%= New DateTime().AddHours(hour).ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")) %>"></option>
<% Next %>
```